# What does the Bible say about Egypt aside from the story of Moses in Exodus?

Tags: ancient-egypt

I am fascinated with ancient civilizations and the civilization that leaves me with the MOST questions is Ancient Egypt. Like many ancient cultures, the Egyptians were very advanced(construction, writing, navigation, astronomy).  I remember being at church once, and the preacher was telling the story of the Exile. While the Egyptians decided to go after Moses( after he parted the sea ) one of the Pharoah's servants said, "They've got God on their side! We must turn back!"

We all know that the Pharoah pushed forward, leading to the death of him and his men.

My question is about the servant's comment.

Were the Egyptians fully aware of the existence of the Christian (at the time Hebrew) God, yet **actively** go against him and live life worshipping their own deities?

How were the Egyptians able to build the most amazing structure on the planet without(or even "actively **against**") God?

Does the Bible shed any light on these ancient "slave-drivers" ?

Comment: _And Pharaoh's servants said unto him, How long shall this man be a snare unto us? let the men go, that they may serve the LORD their God: knowest thou not yet that Egypt is destroyed?_ Exodus 10:7.

Answer (score 4):

It's pretty clear from the Bible that people outside the Hebrews knew about the existence of God.

To make that more specific, they knew that there was a God that the Hebrews worshipped, just as the Hebrews knew there was a god (or gods) that the Egyptians worshipped, and the same for any other race. That doesn't mean they knew that the Hebrew God was the Almighty Creator of the Universe.

They (the Egyptians) might have assumed that he was just one among many gods (or possibly that he didn't exist and the Hebrews made him up). It was a pretty normal assumption in those days that a people thought of their god as one among many - perhaps the best, the most powerful, the one who was on their side, but just one among many.

You might be seeing a number of things going on in Egypt. The Egyptians might assume that the Hebrew god wasn't real, or that their own gods were more powerful. That would explain why Pharaoh might press an attack even knowing that the God of the Hebrews was against him - he is relying on protection from his own gods.

As for your last point, it's never been true that being a follower of God assures you worldly success. Plenty of civilizations have achieved great things without being followers of God.

To answer the bigger question in the title, there are places where you can search the Bible for specific words. [Here are the results of a search for the word "Egypt".](https://www.biblegateway.com/quicksearch/?quicksearch=egypt&qs_version=NIV) You can read all those passages to find out what the Bible says about Egypt. You can also read something called a Bible Dictionary which will tell you all sorts of things about Egypt in the Bible.